# Letter from Matrix 3x3 - search algorithm

Tags: matrix, letter

probably the topic of the thread does not say much about my research and reflection, but I'm in a hurry to explain. The whole task I am about to prepare is quite complex, and this problem is just a tiny subtask, so I won't go into detail about it.

The situation is as follows:
We have a matrix:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i

or

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

free interpretation, because it is not about listing something in the form of e.g. a determinant etc.

The task is to determine a string of characters abcd or 1234 (length [4; 9]) resembling letters or numbers that can be made with one "line" - something like lock pattern in Android.

For example:

```
letter C = 3214789
letter O = 12369874
```

Anyone have an idea how to do this? Thanks in advance for any answers <3

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a model of the characters that can be in the lock pattern.

If your goal is to find the LINES that do this, you could do a brute force search tree where the root of the tree would be one of your nine starting inputs.  You would terminate when your tree covers exactly the the letter in your lock pattern or you have used all 9 inputs.  At each step in the search you could move from the input at X,Y to X-1,Y or X+1, Y or X-1, Y-1, or X+1, Y+1, etc. as long as X, Y were in legal range.

I am sure there are more efficient ways to do this by adding heuristics